# Debug build file with webpack and VS Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, webpack, visual-studio-code

I have a compiled `server.build.js` file that contains server side code, it's the final build for a server-side rendering app with React (ES6 node app with JSX and React).

My objective is to debug the back-end code with the original files, right now I'm able to debug just the bundle file (`server.build.js`) but not the original files that produces it.

I have tried this configuration without success :

[image]

Here the error is obvious, I thought that the debugging process could run the configured outFiles instead of the specified in the program property.

[image]

Then, I tried this configuration, but there is no effect with the breakpoints:

[image]

If someone had success in debugging React server side rendering apps, specifically the backend code, help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: hi! Have you solved this? I'm struggling with the same thing

Comment: Hello @MartinGian , I ended using the --inspect argument while running my app and inspect it with Google Chrome.

Comment: I cannot debug it in Chrome either. For some reason, I am able to see the source map files in the Chrome Dev tool when I’m running the app with —inspect but no matter where I set a breakpoint, it don’t get hit. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50867100/3403218